# Relationship between boiling point and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, phase-transition

In the bubble chamber, liquid hydrogen is kept at high pressure. When a stream of charged particles are injected into the bubble chamber, pressure on the liquid hydrogen is released and bubbles of gas are produced around the charged particles. However my question is that:

why would the boiling point of hydrogen decrease when pressure decreases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boiling point  is the temperature at which the vapor pressure of the liquid equals the pressure at enviornment of liquid and the liquid changes to vapor.

A liquid in a vacuum has a lower boiling point than when that liquid is at atmospheric pressure. In other words, the boiling point of a liquid varies depending upon the surrounding environmental pressure. For a given pressure, different liquids boil at different temperatures
The heat of vaporization is the energy required to transform a given quantity of a substance from a liquid into a gas at a given pressure.
Liquids may change to a vapor at temperatures below their boiling points through the process of evaporation. Evaporation is a surface phenomenon in which molecules of liquid escape into the surroundings as vapor.

Even water will start boiling below 100 degree C when we reduce the pressure.and by furthur decrease in pressure it will start boiling at room temperature.the liquid uses its internal energy to change its phase.